# Weird result when using moment inside loop

Tags: javascript, momentjs

I am trying to use moment inside of a loop to determine how many 60 minutes time slots there is between two dates but I got weird result.

```js
const timeSlots: Moment[] = [];

let startDate = moment('2020-03-09 11:00');
let endDate = moment('2020-03-09 12:30');

while (endDate.diff(startDate, 'minutes') >= 60) {
  timeSlots.push(startDate.clone());
  startDate.add(30, 'minutes');
}

console.log(timeSlots);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.24.0/moment.min.js"></script>
```

Result :

```
2020-03-09 11:00
2020-03-09 11:00
```

Expected :

```
2020-03-09 11:00
2020-03-09 11:30
```

> Weirdly code snippet works but on my computer or on
>   https://playcode.io/ it doesn't

Comment: I made you a snippet. Please do so next time

Comment: I get 10 and 10:30 0Z

Comment: The snippet returns the desired result for me I think?

Comment: The exact same code return different result on the snippet than on my computer or on https://playcode.io/

Comment: Try passing datetime format to moment constructor.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A workaround would be to calculate with the unix timestamp. One hour has 3600 seconds = 3600000 millis:

```js
const timeSlots = [];

let startDate = moment.utc('2020-03-09 11:00').valueOf();
let endDate = moment.utc('2020-03-09 14:30').valueOf();
while ((endDate-startDate) >= 3600000) {
      timeSlots.push(moment.utc(startDate));
      startDate += 3600000;
}

console.log(timeSlots.map(slot => slot.toString()));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.24.0/moment.min.js"></script>
```

### UPDATE:

After some research it seems like the `console.log(timeSlots)` statement is the problem. This logs some internal properties, which we should not care about. It seems to work like expected, if we use:

```js
const timeSlots = [];

let startDate = moment('2020-03-09 11:00');
let endDate = moment('2020-03-09 12:30');

while (endDate.diff(startDate, 'minutes') >= 60) {
  timeSlots.push(startDate.clone());
  startDate.add(30, 'minutes');
}

console.log(timeSlots.map(slot => slot.format()));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.24.0/moment.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Hi, I tried your answer but still same result on my computer and on https://playcode.io/. I don't understand why it works on the stackoverflow snippet

Comment: Hm, that's weird. I updated my answer with a possible workaround.

Comment: It works ... But why ? This behavior is the weirdest I've seen with this library

Comment: I can just guess that it has to do with some local/ timezone stuff and the unix timestamp resolves this, because the unix epoch (January 1st, 1970 at UTC) does not change, no matter where you are on the globe.

Comment: I don't know ... Because the result on my computer is the same two time : 11h00 so it is not related with the local/timezone stuffs

Comment: This kept on nagging at me... so after some research I found that only the log was the problem. I updated my answer.  Please let me know if this solved the problem for you too.

Comment: Ok, so apparently both version : .toString() or .format() works when you use the map. The one that don't work is to use console.log directly on it. I use the website https://playcode.io/ to reproduce the same behavior than in my computer